# From CSV to JSON with Library PapaParse: 139.420248 =>"139.420.248"?

Tags: javascript, html, papaparse

I'm using [PapaParse](https://www.papaparse.com/) to convert a `CSV` file to `JSON`. Unfortunately PapaParse converts numbers to a wrong format - strings in this case:

`139.420248`

becomes

`"139.420.248"`

**Input CSV string:**
`35.447998,139.419287,2014-02-02 12:18:32`

Result:

```
latitude:"35.447.998"
longitude:"139.419.287"
time_stampe:"02.02.2014 12:18"
```

My Papaparse code:

```
   function parseData(url, callBack) {
     Papa.parse(url, {`
     download: true,
     dynamicTyping: true,
     header: true,
     complete: function (results) { callBack(results.data); }
     });
   }
```

Comment: Well you probably don’t want to set `dynamicTyping: true` then …?

Comment: Thanks for your succession but I already tried that :)

Comment: Is this still happening? I tried recreating your problem with the provided code but I was unable to recreate the problem. Please provide more code to clarify.